# How can I get graphql-ruby to use joins when accessing subfields?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graphql, graphql-ruby

I have a model like this

```rb
class Foo
  has_many :bars
end
```

and a query like this

```
query foos(
  $offset: Int
  $sort_by: String
  $should_paginate: Boolean
) {
  foos(
    offset: $offset
    sort_by: $sort_by
    should_paginate: $should_paginate
  ) {
    id
    name
    bars {
```

When I fetch this query, I get one `select * from "foos"` for each bar that's in the collection.

How can I have this all be smarter and do fewer SQL queries?

Answer (score 1):

Look at https://github.com/Shopify/graphql-batch

It uses allows you to lazy-load your associations at once on demand.

Comment: It solves the n+1 problem, but not the other problems w/ association-based loading, which is that you will not be able to sort/filter by child attributes.

Best way I've found to do _that_ is to use a database view and create another model/type in graphql-ruby for that view

Comment: @hedgehogrider try something like this: https://github.com/Shopify/graphql-batch/blob/master/examples/association_loader.rb